# Trying to work through SSIS Tutorial: Creating a Simple ETL Package for SQL Server 2012

Tags: sql-server, ssis, etl

I am trying to work through this example to create an SSIS package but the query doesn't work on step 6, and it appears there is no "dbo.dimcurrency" table in this database. I get the following error on executing the query.. 
Msg 208, Level 16, State 1, Line 2
Invalid object name 'dbo.DimCurrency'.

https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/5c59f723-9707-4407-80ae-f05f483cf65f(v=sql.110)

```
<code> use AdventureWorks2012;
 Select * from (select * from [dbo].[DimCurrency]) as refTable
where [refTable].[CurrencyAlternateKey] = 'ARS'
OR
[refTable].[CurrencyAlternateKey] = 'AUD'
OR
[refTable].[CurrencyAlternateKey] = 'BRL'
OR
[refTable].[CurrencyAlternateKey] = 'CAD'
OR
[refTable].[CurrencyAlternateKey] = 'CNY'
OR
[refTable].[CurrencyAlternateKey] = 'DEM'
OR
[refTable].[CurrencyAlternateKey] = 'EUR'
OR
[refTable].[CurrencyAlternateKey] = 'FRF'
OR
[refTable].[CurrencyAlternateKey] = 'GBP'
OR
[refTable].[CurrencyAlternateKey] = 'JPY'
OR
[refTable].[CurrencyAlternateKey] = 'MXN'
OR
[refTable].[CurrencyAlternateKey] = 'SAR'
OR
[refTable].[CurrencyAlternateKey] = 'USD'
OR
[refTable].[CurrencyAlternateKey] = 'VEB'

</code>
```

Answer (score 3):

You need to have installed the [AdventureWorksDW2012](http://msftdbprodsamples.codeplex.com/releases/view/55330) database to do this tutorial. You are trying to read from the table `[dbo].[DimCurrency]` which does not exist. Refer to the requirements [here](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms169917(v=sql.110).aspx#Anchor_1).

**Update:**

You can create the [dbo].[DimCurrency] table with the following SQL, this should get rid of your error (though the table will obviously be empty):

```
USE AdventureWorks2012
CREATE TABLE [dbo].[DimCurrency]
      (
        [CurrencyAlternateKey] nchar(3) NOT NULL,
        [CurrencyKey] int NOT NULL,
        [CurrencyName] nvarchar(50) NOT NULL
      );
```

Comment: The Database has been installed but there is no DimCurrency table within it anywhere.

Comment: Apparently there is a simpler page to find the install here. <http://msftdbprodsamples.codeplex.com/releases/view/105902> other page has like 12 different downloads and is confusing, I have the Dim.Currency table now so the download may have been corrupted or incorrect, thank you.

Comment: If you do use the SQL the script still fails at dbo.DimDate. So finding the right release looks a better way to go. The link webdev8183 provided currently looks broke.

Comment: It looks like you need the AdventureWorksDW db and not just the AdventureWorks one. I used this link which seems to populate the tables: http://msftdbprodsamples.codeplex.com/downloads/get/165405